# Where to publish quantum algorithm related paper

Tags: quantum-algorithms, research

I am an undergraduate student and I wrote a paper for my research program on quantum information. To be more specific, it is about using a novel quantum algorithm to do signal/image processing. It won me a distinction in the research program so I thought I might want to try to publish it somewhere. However, I found it quite hard to find a suitable journal/conference to publish this paper on such a interdisciplinary topic. Anyone could give some suggestions as to where I can try to submit it to? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be more specific and as an addendum to Drito's answer which provides a good starting point  for your search, I would like to narrow it down for you, by recommending **Quantum Information Processing**. Since this journal is good, and moreover it has papers regarding Image Processing related topics like its Representation, security.

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://rdvlivefromtokyo.blogspot.com/2019/11/quantum-information-theory-computing.html) is a good list made by Prof. Rod Van Meter.

Maybe you could look at the papers you based your work off of and see where they were published? That should give you a sense of which journals are interested in the sort of work you've done.

Comment: 'Maybe you could look at the papers you based your work off of and see where they were published?' because I feel that those journal standard is too demanding for a undergraduate student like me, so I am trying to find somewhere relatively friendlier for me. Thank you for your list anyways.

Comment: Ah if you're looking for a bit of a less intensive process, I vaguely remember there being undergraduate-aimed journals on general science stuff, maybe they would accept QI projects as well?

Comment: May I know which journals you are referring to?

Comment: Here's one: spsnational.org/jurp